# How to install MSbuild to build my dotnet framework project in Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to use Gitlab to fullfill CICD.

```
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
  - shared-windows
  - windows
  - windows-1809
variables:
  MSBUILD_PATH: './tools/msbuild.exe'

stages:
  - build

build:
  extends:
  - .shared_windows_runners
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
  script: 
    - echo "test"
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" WebCICD.sln'
```

My .Net version: .NET Framework 4.6.2

Below is ok but I don't know how can I install MSBuild.

I download MSBuild from the download page.

It was a file named BuildTools_Full.exe

Seems like an installer file.

Should I just push it to gitlab and treat it like bin file?

Then try to type "Msbuild.exe myProject"?

My repo: https://gitlab.com/catsheue/dotnetframeworkcicd

Comment: which .NET version are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using .Net framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the MSBuild already or you just downloaded it, then make a new variable and set the path to the msbuild.exe file and then just use it in your script. The path I added in the snippet is the default installation path. It might work for you too. Otherwise you need to figure out where that msbuild.exe is.

```
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
  - shared-windows
  - windows
  - windows-1809
variables:
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe' or the path to msbuild.exe

stages:
  - build

build:
  extends:
  - .shared_windows_runners
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
  script: 
    -'& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" YOUR_PROJECT.sln /p:Configuration="YOUR_CONF"
```

Comment: Hi thanks MrJami, here I encounter a problem,
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
I put the msbuild in my git repo, ./tools/msbuild.exe

Comment: dont put it into your git repo. You need to install msbuild.exe on your gitlab-runner docker